# CSS `display:none` effect on DOM

Tags: html, css

Hi I wanted to know what the effect of applying `display:none` to an element is. Does it remove it from the DOM or just from the document flow? What does removing an element from the document flow implies? I know that `visibility: hidden` just hides the element, but it still affects the document flow and that you can remove an element from the DOM using the `remove()` js method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: none;` will just hide the element, but all the listener events will still be there. It won't be removed from the DOM.
But the difference between `visibility: hidden` and `display: none` is that, in first case, the tag and content inside will be rendered, whereas in second case the tag won't be rendered.

`visibility: hidden;`
[image]

`div` tag is rendered and affecting document flow

`display: none;`
[image]

`div` not rendered

Comment: jQuery can remove it.

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS,  as can plain old javascript. What CSS can't do is change the DOM, only how it is represented.

Comment: @Pushkin So whats the difference with visibility:hidden, does it not hide the element aswell?

Comment: @FRANCISCOBERNAD, in both case, it will be hidden, unlike `display: none`, the element will be rendered in `visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 2):

Using display:none; will make the element disappear, like it has never been there, visibility: hidden; will hide it only, making it kinda transparent and it will disturb document flow